# How to automatically include some where conditions in rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several models with `office_id`, `fiscal_year_id` attributes. I want these field to automatically set before querying. So, I don't have to care about data overlapping from one office to another and one fiscal year to another.

Comment: That would be `default_scope` but its regarded as [a huge anti-pattern](https://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2015/9/19/default-scopes-anti-pattern.html). Instead write a class method that returns the scope you want and call it instead of `MyModel.all`.

Comment: Also please don't use all the rails version tags. They are not ornaments and will not attract additional attention as very few people follow the version tags. They should only serve to tell readers what version of rails this question applies to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSuppport::CurrentAttributes provides what you need.

See docs [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

app/models/concern/fiscalable.rb

```
module Fiscalable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def office_id
    super || 1 # default office_id
  end

  def fiscal_year_id
    super || Time.zone.now.year
  end
end
```

And in your models.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord
  include Fiscalable 
  ...
end
```

In views.

```
<%= @object.fiscal_year_id %>
```

Comment: Can I set default automatically immediately after login? And can I access current_user in the module.

Comment: I don't think the author is asking about attribute defaults. Rather he is looking for something like `default_scope`. Anyways this is not how you want to do default attributes as there is a boatload of problems with this approach. Use `attribute :attribute_name, default: 'some_value'` unless you're on a rails version older than 5.0 or you have a database default.